# Use Sybase triggers to write dynamic statement using all old and new values for creating your own replication transaction statement log?

Tags: loops, triggers, sybase, dynamic-sql, advantage-database-server

## PROBLEM SUMMARY

I have to write I/U/D-statement-generating-triggers for a bucardo/symmetricDS-inspired homemade bidirectional replication system between Sybase ADS and Postgresql 11 groups of nodes, using BEFORE triggers on any Postgresql and Sybase DB that creates Insert/Update/Delete commands based on the command entered in a replicating source table: e.g. an `INSERT INTO PERSON (first_name,last_name,gender,age,ethnicity) Values ('John','Doe','M',42,'C')` and manipulate them into a corresponding Insert statement, and UPDATE by getting OLD and NEW values to dynamically make an UPDATE statement, along with getting OLD values to make a DELETE command, all to run per command on a destination at some interval.

I know this is difficult and no one does this but it is for a job and I have no other options and can't object to offer a different solution. I have no other teammates or human resources to help outside of SO and something like Codementors, which was not so helpful. My idea/strategy is to copy parts of bucardo/SymmetricDS when inserting OLD and NEW values for generating a statement/command to run on the destination. Right now, I am snapshotting the whole table to a CSV as opposed to doing by individual command, but by command and looping through table that generates and saves commands will make the job much easier.

One big issue is that they come from Sybase ADS and have a mixed Key/Index structure (many tables have NO PK) and are mirroring that in Postgresql, so I am trying to write PK-less statements, or all-column commands to get around the no-pk tables. They also will only replicate certain columns for certain tables, so I have a column in a table for them to insert the column names delimited by ';' and then split it out into an array and link the column names to the values for each statement to generate a full command for I/U/D, Hopefully. I am open to other strategies but this is a big solo project and I have gone at it many ways with much difficulty.

I mostly come from DBA background and have some programming experience with the fundamentals, so I am mostly pseudocoding each major sequence,googling for syntax by part, and adjusting as I go or encounter a language incapability. I am thankful for any help given, as I am getting a bit desperate and discouraged.

## WHAT I HAVE TRIED

I have to do this for Sybase ADS and Postgresql but this question is intially over ADS since it's more challenging and older.

To have one "Log" table which tracks row changes for each of the replicating tables and records and ultimately dynamically generates a command is the goal for both platforms. I am trying to make trigger statements like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PERSON_INSERT
ON PERSON
BEFORE 
INSERT
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Backlog (SourceTableID, TriggerType, Status, CreateTimeDate, NewValues) select ID, 'INSERT','READY', NOW(),''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity'' from __new;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER PERSON_UPDATE
   ON PERSON
   BEFORE 
   UPDATE 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Backlog (SourceTableID, TriggerType, Status, CreateTimeDate, NewValues) select ID, 'U','UPDATE','READY', NOW(),''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity'' from __new;
UPDATE Backlog SET OldValues=select ''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity'' from __old where SourceTableID=select ID from __old;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER PERSON_DELETE
   ON PERSON
   BEFORE 
   DELETE 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Backlog (SourceTableID, TriggerType, Status, CreateTimeDate, OldValues) select ID, 'D','DELETE','READY', NOW(),''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity'' from __old;
END;
```

but I would like the "''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity''" to come from another table as a value to make it dynamic since multiple tables will write their value and statement info to the single log table. Then, it can be made into a variable and then probably split to link to the corresponding values so the IUD statements can be made which will be executed on the destination one at a time.

## ATTEMPTED INCOMPLETE SAMPLE TRIGGER CODE

```
CREATE TRIGGER PERSON_INSERT
   ON PERSON
   BEFORE 
INSERT
BEGIN
--Declare @Columns string
--@Columns=select Columns from metatable where tablename='PERSON'
--String Split(@Columns,';') into array to correspond to new and old VALUES
--@NewValues=@['@Columns='+NEW.@Columns+'']
INSERT INTO Backlog (SourceTableID, TriggerType, Status, CreateTimeDate, NewValues) select ID, 'INSERT','READY', NOW(),''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity'' from __new;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER PERSON_UPDATE
   ON PERSON
   BEFORE 
   UPDATE 
BEGIN 
--Declare @Columns string
--@Columns=select Columns from metatable where tablename='PERSON'
--String Split(@Columns,';') into array to correspond to new and old VALUES
--@NewValues=@['@Columns='+NEW.@Columns+'']
--@OldValues=@['@Columns='+OLD.@Columns+'']
INSERT INTO Backlog (SourceTableID, TriggerType, Status, CreateTimeDate, NewValues) select ID, 'U','UPDATE','READY', NOW(),''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity'' from __new;
UPDATE Backlog SET OldValues=select ''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity'' from __old where SourceTableID=select ID from __old;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER PERSON_DELETE
   ON PERSON
   BEFORE 
   DELETE 
BEGIN 
--Declare @Columns string
--@Columns=select Columns from metatable where tablename='PERSON'
--String Split(@Columns,',') into array to correspond to new and old VALUES
--@OldValues=@['@Columns='+OLD.@Columns+'']
INSERT INTO Backlog (SourceTableID, TriggerType, Status, CreateTimeDate, OldValues) select ID, 'D','DELETE','READY', NOW(),''first_name';'last_name';'gender';'age';'ethnicity'' from __old;
END;
```

## CONCLUSION

For each row inserted,updated, or deleted; in a COMMAND column in the log table, I am trying to generate a corresponding 'INSERT INTO PERSON ('+@Columns+') VALUES ('+@NewValues+')' type statement, or an UPDATE or DELETE. Then a Foreach service will run each command value ordered by create time, as the main replication service.

To be clear, I am trying to make my sample code trigger write all old values and new values to a column in a dynamic way without hardcoding the columns in each trigger since it will be used for multiple tables, and writing the values into a single column delimited by a comma or semicolon.

An even bigger wish or goal behind this is to find a way to save/script each IUD command and then be able to run them on subscriber server.DBs of postgresql and Sybase platform, therefore making my own replication from a log

Comment: So, what is your question then? You describe your background very well, but what is the actual problem? You need help writing you SQL code?

Comment: Yes, help writing a trigger that can get all old or new values for the triggered table it's part of and write them into a single column value in a log table delimited by commas or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It is a complex but solvable problem that would take time and careful planning to write.  I think what you are looking for is the "Execute Immediate" command in ADS SQL syntax.  With this command you can create a dynamic statement to then be executed once construction of the SQL statement is terminated.  Save each desired column value to a temp table by carefully constructing the statement as a string and then execute it with Execute Immediate.  For example:

```
DECLARE TableColumns Cursor ; 
DECLARE FldName Char(100) ;
...
OPEN TableColumns AS SELECT * 
                       FROM system.columns 
                      WHERE parent = @cTableName 
                        AND field_type < 21 //ADS_ROWVERSION
                        AND field_type <> 6 //ADS_BINARY 
                        AND field_type <> 7; //ADS_IMAGE

While Fetch TableColumns DO

    FldName = Trim( TableColumns.Name) ;

    StrSql = 'SELECT New.[' + Trim( FldName ) + '] newVal' +
             'INTO #myTmpTable FROM ___New n' ;
```

After constructing the statement as a string it can then be executed like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STRSQL ;
```

You can pickup old and new values from __old and __new temp tables that are always available to triggers.  Insert values into temp table myTmpTable and then use it to update the target.   Remember to drop myTmpTable at the end.

Furthermore, I would think you can create a function on the DD that can actually be called from each trigger on the tables you want to keep track of instead of writing a long trigger for each table and cTableName can be a parameter sent to the function.  That would make maintenance a little easier.